# Count cells with different conditional ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to count cells with conditional ranges of different sizes, using only one(two) standard function(s) with maybe nested functions? Important - without VBA and multiple functions additions like COUNTIFS(...) + COUNTIFS(...) + COUNTIFS(...) and so on. Excel 2016.

For example, we have two ranges A1:E3 and F1:F3. Two criterias: "John" and "Apple". So, the goal is to count cells, where "Apple" in 1st range matches "John" in 2nd range.

[image: test data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Apple` can only happen once per row in the range then a simple SUMPRODUCT will do what you want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:C3="Apple")*(D1:D3="John"))
```

[image]

If it can happen multiple times per row and you only want each row to count once then we need to use MMULT with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(--(A1:C3="Apple"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:C3)^0))>0)*(D1:D3="John"))
```

[image]